# JHipster React Show List Of One Entity in Details Screen of Another Related Entity

Tags: java, spring, react-redux, jhipster

I am attempting an application in JHipster 7.0.1 (Azul JDK 11) and ReactJS as the front-end.

I have 2 entities in my JDL - Domain and BadgeCategory that are related as shown below

```
relationship OneToMany {
    Domain{badgeClass required} to BadgeCategory{domain(name) required}
```

I want to be able to display all the BadgeCategories for a particular Domain in the Domain Detail screen.

For this, I created a new method in the repository **BadgeCategoryRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface BadgeCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<BadgeCategory, Long> {
    List<BadgeCategory> findByDomainId(Long id);
}
```

And then added a new endpoint in **BadgeCategoryResource.java**

```java
@GetMapping("/badge-categories-domain/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<BadgeCategory>> getAllBadgeCategoriesForDomain(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get BadgeCategories for Domain : {}", id);
    List<BadgeCategory> badgeCategory = badgeCategoryRepository.findByDomainId(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(badgeCategory);
}
```

Now coming to the React part, I added a constant in **badge-category.reducer.ts**

```js
export const getEntitiesForDomain = createAsyncThunk(
  'badgeCategory/fetch_entity_list_for_domain', 
  async (id: string) => {
    const requestUrl = `api/badge-categories-domain/${id}`;
    alert(JSON.stringify(axios.get<IBadgeCategory[]>(requestUrl)));
    return axios.get<IBadgeCategory[]>(requestUrl);
  });
```

Then I am using this reducer in the Domain Detail screen component **domain-detail.tsx**

```js
import { getEntity as getBadgeCategory, getEntitiesForDomain } from '../badge-category/badge-category.reducer';

  const domainEntity = useAppSelector(state => state.domain.entity);
  const badgeCategoryList = useAppSelector(state => state.badgeCategory.entities);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEntity(props.match.params.id));
    dispatch(getEntitiesForDomain(props.match.params.id));
  }, []);
```

I am expecting the constant badgeCategoryList to contain the list of all badge categories for the domain which is being referred to in the domain-detail screen. But I get nothing in return.

On checking the flow, I see that the endpoint is getting hit and the response is being produced by the Java code, but the UI code is not able to consume it.

What am I missing here that is causing this issue?

[image: ConsoleLogs]

The Swagger docs show expected response from the Java code

[image: Swagger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with the new API call not being registered with the slice section in the reducer. I had to do the following addition to the slice and it works like a charm

```js
.addMatcher(isFulfilled(getEntitiesForDomain), (state, action) => {
   return {
     ...state,
     loading: false,
     entities: action.payload.data,
   };
})
```